# Compression on serialization

Tags: ruby, serialization, compression, thrift

I serialized a 116k file to thrift binary format using the compact protocol but even after serializing, the size is 116K. Isnt the serializer supposed to reduce the file size? The file contains only strings, if that info helps.

Are there any other data serialization techniques that will reduce the size of my object?

I tried protobuf serialization but that also didnt reduce the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serializer is supposed to serialize stuff. Serialization is a process of converting in-memory object graph to a byte stream, suitable for storing on disk or sending over the network.

To compress this byte stream, you need a compressor.